# Pandas: cannot filter based on string equality

Tags: python, string, pandas, filtering, selection

Using pandas 0.16.2 on python 2.7, OSX.

I read a data-frame from a csv file like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("my_csv_file.csv",sep='\t', skiprows=(0), header=(0))
```

The output of `data.dtypes` is:

```
name       object
weight     float64
ethnicity  object
dtype: object
```

I was expecting string types for name, and ethnicity. But I found reasons here on SO on why they're "object" in newer pandas versions.

Now, I want to select rows based on ethnicity, for example:

```
data[data['ethnicity']=='Asian']
Out[3]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name, weight, ethnicity]
Index: []
```

I get the same result with `data[data.ethnicity=='Asian']` or     `data[data['ethnicity']=="Asian"]`.

But when I try the following:

```
data[data['ethnicity'].str.contains('Asian')].head(3)
```

I get the results I want.

However, I do not want to use "contains"- I would like to check for direct equality.

Please note that `data[data['ethnicity'].str=='Asian']` raises an error.

Am I doing something wrong? How to do this correctly?

Comment: You probably don't have that value in your df which is why it fails, are you sure you have that exact string?

Comment: Does your string data contains some leading and trailing white characters?

Comment: Post `data.loc[data['ethnicity'].str.contains('Asian'), 'ethnicity'].head(3).tolist()`. It will help you see if there is whitespace in your strings.

Comment: both answers below were correct and they solved my problem. Turns out, this is because of whitespace. It was difficult choosing between two correct answers. I ended up marking answer that was more detailed. Hope that's ok. It was just like a coin-toss.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is probably whitespace in your strings, for example,

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'ethnicity':[' Asian', '  Asian']})
data.loc[data['ethnicity'].str.contains('Asian'), 'ethnicity'].tolist()
# [' Asian', '  Asian']
print(data[data['ethnicity'].str.contains('Asian')])
```

yields

```
  ethnicity
0     Asian
1     Asian
```

To strip the leading or trailing whitespace off the strings, you could use

```
data['ethnicity'] = data['ethnicity'].str.strip()
```

after which,

```
data.loc[data['ethnicity'] == 'Asian']
```

yields

```
  ethnicity
0     Asian
1     Asian
```

Answer (score 5):

You might try this:

```
data[data['ethnicity'].str.strip()=='Asian']
```